# Too many arguments error in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am writing a script to delete all files in a directory for practice. I am using quotes around my variables, and yet I am still getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/deleteall: line 6: [: too many arguments
/usr/local/bin/deleteall: line 11: [: too many arguments
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Deletes all files in the current directory

read -p "You are about to delete all files in $(pwd). Are you sure you want to do this? y/n" yn
echo $yn
if [ [ "$yn" = "y" ] -o [ "$yn" = "Y" ] ] ; then
        for i in `ls`; do
                rm $i
        done
        exit;
elif [ [ "$yn" = "n" ] -o [ "$yn" = "N" ] ] ; then
        exit;
else
        read -p "Please enter y (yes) or n (no)"
        exit;
fi
```

And this is the entire output:

```
You are about to delete all files in <my dir>. Are you sure you want to do this? y/nn
n
/usr/local/bin/deleteall: line 6: [: too many arguments
/usr/local/bin/deleteall: line 11: [: too many arguments
Please enter y (yes) or n (no)n
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line appears to be problem:

```
if [ [ "$yn" = "y" ] -o [ "$yn" = "Y" ] ] ; then
```

You can replace this with:

```
if [[ "$yn" == [yY] ]]; then
```

**PS:** Do same for the line where you check `n or N`.

Comment: @WilliamOliver: Because your syntax was incorrect. It should have been: `[ "$yn" = 'y' -o "$yn" = 'Y' ]`

Comment: @mrjink Not in Bash conditionals

Comment: @WilliamOliver: No that's not true. You can use `[[ and ]]` wherever you've used `[ and ]`. `[` is actually a separate binary and `[[` is BASH's internal construct so performance wise `[[ and ]]` will be better.

Comment: More specifically, `[` is a command name, not syntax for grouping, so you cannot just nest them like you attempted.

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest `[]`. It's literally interpreting the nested brackets as arguments, and printing an error that you have too many.

Just this will work

```
if [ "$yn" = "y" -o "$yn" = "Y" ]; then
```

Another alternate syntax using double brackets and same logic

```
if [[ $yn == "y" || $yn == "Y" ]]; then
```

Also

```
for i in `ls`; do
  rm $i
done
```

Should really be

```
for i in *; do
  [ -f "$i" ] && rm $i
done
```

So it only tries to remove regular files (you will get errors for dirs, unless you overwrote `rm`, and you can decide what you want to do with symlinks). And `ls` is simply extraneous.

Comment: is there a way to do nested conditionals in Bash?

Comment: @WilliamOliver Not as far as I know, but I can't think of a case where that would be a problem. Just use and/or and their respective symbols, or nest if blocks with conditions.

Comment: "Nested conditionals" doesn't really make sense. I think you're looking for grouping, which can be done with parentheses: `if [[ ( "$yn" = "y" ) || ( "$yn" = "Y" ) ]]; then`. However, because `[` is a regular command, if you use that instead of `[[`, you must escape the parentheses: `if [ \( "$yn" = "y" \) -o \( "$yn" = "Y" \) ]; then`.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want:

```
read -p "Are you sure? " -n 1 -r
echo    # (optional) move to a new line
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
     for i in `ls`; do
      rm -rf $i
done
fi

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Nn]$ ]]
then
     #do what you want
done
fi
```